# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Register.CountryId'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine, razor-declarative-helpers

The code was working, but I am not getting the error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'Register.CountryId'

**In view**:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "NMPAccount", new { @id = "myForm", @name = "myForm" }))

 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Register.CountryId)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Register.CountryId, Model.Register.CountryList,  
                                                    new { @id = "CountryList" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.CountryId)

}
```

**In controller**:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register() {
    var registerViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
    registerViewModel.Initalize();
    return View("Register", registerViewModel);

}

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            model.Initalize();
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "");
            return View("Register", model);

        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Register != null) {
            if (RegisterViewModel.RegisterNewUser(model.Register))
                return RedirectToAction("RegisterSuccess");
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", NMPAccountResource.Failed);

        }
```

**in ViewModel:**

```
public class RegisterViewModel {
        public RegisterViewModel() {
            Register = new RegisterModel();
        }

        public RegisterModel Register { get; set; }

        public void Initalize() {
            var registerUser = new RegisterUser();
            IList<CountryCodes> couList = Utilities.GetCountryList(languageId);
            var countryList = (from data in couList
                               select new CustomItem() {
                                   Id = data.CountryCodesId,
                                   Description = data.CountryName

                               }).ToList();
            if (countryList.Count > 0) {
                countryList[0].Id = null;
            }


            var clist = new SelectList(countryList, "Id", "Description");

            Register.CountryList = clist;
        }
```

** Register Model**:

```
   public string CountryId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
```

I want to do this from  "view model".

I have searched *StackOverflow*, but I have not found an answer to solve my problem.

Comment: please told me solution and cause of that problem in mvc razor???

Comment: please help me to get solution of this problem

Comment: change in view.=> `m.Register.CountryId` to `m.register.CountryList`..let me know if that works i will add reason

Comment: I couldn't add that as a comment, but we cant see if you return a view in the `else` section of the controller?

Comment: Are you setting `ViewData` somewhere too? can you post the full view?

Comment: i does not set ViewData ,i  had  added form of view in post

Comment: Also, whats in the view `RegisterSuccess`? at what point do you see the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't add this as a comment, but you need to return a view model in the POST version of the `Register` Action

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                model.Initalize();
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "");
                return View("Register", model);

            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Register != null) {
                if (RegisterViewModel.RegisterNewUser(model.Register))
                    return RedirectToAction("RegisterSuccess");
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", NMPAccountResource.Failed);
               //there needs to be code here to return the view.
               return View("Register", model); //<--- this is missing
               }

            }
               //there needs to be code here to return the view.
               return View("Register", model); //<--- this is missing

   }
```

Your code might have been working previously if the condition `!ModelState.IsValid` was **TRUE**.  Maybe you've not got passed this check, and the code below fails at run-time.

Comment: what should be the solution?can you suggest me clearly,i does not get solution till now??please comment me?

Comment: You need to make sure you're returning the ViewModel in the `ELSE` blocks, see above...

Comment: still has problem   in this issue

Comment: Lower case will suffice, have you made the above alterations to your `Register` method?